# Qt5 QML organizing resources into folder

Tags: qml, qt5

I want to put some .qml files into folders.

this works,

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>other/Thing.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

but this doesn't

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>

    <qresource prefix="/other">
        <file>other/Thing.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

im separating because the next step is to move the "/other" resource into a separate qrc file.

any help? thanks.

EDIT 1:

i try this,

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/other">
        <file>other/Thing.qml</file>
        <file>other/qmldir</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

qmldir:

```
module Other
Thing 1.0 Thing.qml
```

then add to main.qml:

```
import Other 1.0
```

EDIT #2

i try adding to main.cpp:

```
engine.addImportPath("other");
```

or

```
engine.addImportPath("qrc:/other");
```

no go.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9d82204dac684263e257

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to add an import path *within the resources*.

```
engine.addImportPath("qrc:/Other");
```

file set here,

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/314e95bc6cfc0ed6b3b5

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that problem you encounter related to difference in letters case when you reference your "other" folder. You use sometimes "Other", sometimes "other".

Try this:

```
import other 1.0;
```

Instead of

```
import Other 1.0;
```

It seems that qt takes into account real name of folder, not the name specified in qmldir.

Comment: Good idea. Qt seems to like things starting with capitals. I lost some time on this fixing another problem. I'm posting my answer below, there's a bit more to it.